# Can we use use PLSQL function in the WITH clause which is in the inner select?

Tags: sql, view, oracle12c

Starting 12c oracle provides a way to define function in WITH clause of SQL query.

But for below sample query template it fails. Is there any way we can do this? As we are creating view as as per below format.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
WITH FUNCTION 
FUNCTION_NAME 
RETURN DATE
IS
DATE_V DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT SOMEDATE INTO 
DATE_V 
FROM SOMETABLE;
RETURN DATE_V;
END;
SELECT FUNCTION_NAME FROM 
DUAL;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `WITH FUNCTION` inside `SELECT` statement. Following may help you:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_sql     VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_value   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_sql := 'WITH
              FUNCTION test(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
              BEGIN
                RETURN p_id;
              END;
            SELECT test(1)
            FROM   dual';
  OPEN l_cursor FOR l_sql;
  FETCH l_cursor INTO l_value;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_value=' || l_value);
  CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
/
```

Then you can use `l_value` for further action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [move the function declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABJFIDC) before the SELECT:

```
WITH 
  FUNCTION FUNCTION_NAME 
  RETURN DATE
  IS
    DATE_V DATE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT SOMEDATE INTO 
      DATE_V 
    FROM SOMETABLE;
    RETURN DATE_V;
  END;
SELECT FUNCTION_NAME 
FROM DUAL
/
```

This requires 12.2 as far as I remember, 12.1 is not enough

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f28f2e945bb734319232314fb84f013b)